# Merging multiple arrays of objects of the same length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here are examples of the arrays that I need to merge

```
const urls = [{url:"http:/..."},{url:"http:/..."},{url:"http:/..."}]; 
const images = [{image:"..."},{image:"..."},{image:"..."}];

const merged = [{url:"http:/...", image:"..."},{url:"http:/...", image:"..."},{url:"http:/...", image:"..."}]
```

I have tried Object.assign({},urls, images). That ends up just deleting urls in that instance because it does not deep copy. The keys for each object in the array are the same!

Comment: you can use manual merging - use loop `for()` and create new objects... simple I think

Answer (score 4):

If you are certainly sure they are both equal size, you definitely can run through one of them with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method.
Actually, you should use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if you want to merge an object with a more generic way.

```js
const urls = [{url:"http:/..."},{url:"http:/..."},{url:"http:/..."}]; 
const images = [{image:"..."},{image:"..."},{image:"..."}];

const results = urls.map((url, index) => 
   Object.assign({}, url, images[index])
);

console.log(results)
```

**ES6**

you can use ES6 instead of Object.assign.

```
const results = urls.map((url, index) => 
  ({...url, ...images[index]})
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over one of the arrays and use the index to get the other array's item:

```js
const urls = [{url:"http:/0..."},{url:"http:/1..."},{url:"http:/2..."}]; 
const images = [{image:"0..."},{image:"1..."},{image:"2..."}];

const newArray = urls.map((url, i) => ({...url, ...images[i] }) )

console.log(newArray)
```

Or you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this:

```js
const urls = [{url:"http:/0..."},{url:"http:/1..."},{url:"http:/2..."}],
      images = [{image:"0..."},{image:"1..."},{image:"2..."}];

const length = urls.length

const newArray = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => ({ ...urls[i], ...images[i] }) )
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over one of the arrays using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and using the index provided to the callback function, you can get corresponding value in the other array.

Here's an example:

```js
const urls = [{url:"http:/..."},{url:"http:/..."},{url:"http:/..."}]; 
const images = [{image:"..."},{image:"..."},{image:"..."}];

console.log(urls.map((t, id) => ({ image: images[id].image, url: t.url })));
```

Here the parameters passed into the callback function are `t`: the item from `urls` array and `id`: index of `t` in `urls` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the arrays and assign the object to the object with the same index.

This works for an arbitrary count of arrays.

```js
const
    urls = [{url:"http:/..."}, { url: "http:/..." }, { url: "http:/..." }],
    images = [{ image: "..." }, { image: "..." }, { image: "..." }],
    result = [urls, images]
        .reduce((r, a) => (
            a.forEach((o, i) => Object.assign(r[i] = r[i] || {}, o)),
            r
        ), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```